# Use expo partially with RN with custom native-modules

Tags: react-native, expo

I'd like to try expo for faster development.

It's said that you can't use native-module if you use expo.
But it seems it's possible to use native-module if you `eject` or use `bare` mode. (not sure if they are the same)

Or it seems it's even possible to start from RN-cli and add expo features.

Are they all the same in what we can do in the end?
How about apk size? Is there a way to cut down the 20-25M file size by starting from RN-cli and adding Expo on top of it or by ejecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that and achieve 25M File size.
But, I will give you a good solution if you want expo functionality as well as the Native capabilities.

You can try the bare minimum setup with expo.

What it will do is, It will create a `react-native init` project with `unimodules`.
`Unimodules` will have access to some basic expo features, for example `permissions` etc etc.
And in future if you want to add some other expo feature (which supports bare apps).
You can add them pretty easily.
In expo docs, you can check which features are available in bare apps and which are not.
The main concern for me is that bare apps don't support the background tasks of expo yet.
I always start my apps with this. But the downside would be that the app would be around 30-35mb,
You can still try to minimize it 
https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640

Answer (score 0):

Expo has group of packages provided by expo.io. The app built with expo has bigger apk size because we are also bundling the packages which we are not even using. these are the packages comes with expo

https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages

Best solution to reduce apk size is start with building app without expo then add only required dependencies. If your project needs expo features you can use Expo kit

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/expokit/

Thank you